# How can I print a message once my scrapy has crawled all the intended pages?

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to print a simple message -

```
print("---------------The crawling is now completed..!!----------")
```

But I never get this message on the console.

I'm not sure where does the scrapy flow of control goes after it completes the crawl process.

I'm trying to print this msg in my main spider.py file. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been resolved.
We can simply make a new method inside the pipelines.py file:

```
def close_spider(self,spider):
```

Whatever we write inside this is executed after the spider has completed the crawling.